# 2xAA + 5V Boost Converter: Unexpectedly Low Current Output

Tags: boost, alkaline

I'm quite new to electronics, and decided to make a mobile powerbank for my Raspberry Pi Zero / Phone out of 2xAA Batteries and a 5V, 600mA boost converter with USB output. However, I'm getting an unexpectedly low output of only 0.08~0.10mA @ 4.5~5V when charging! I'm trying to figure out why this is.

My components are:

2x Panasonic AA Batteries at full charge. I'm having a very hard time researching the amount of current these are able to provide, but as far as I understand from the datasheet and a bit of googling, they should be able to output 1000mA above 1.2V

1x 0.9~5V 5V 600mA Boost Converter

2x Small Alligator Clips soldered on to the positive and negative through-holes of the boost converter.

1x AA box where I mount the batteries in series.

By my reckoning, my two batteries should output roughly 1A @ 3V, which equates to 3 Watts. But I'm getting only 0.08A @ 5V, amounting to a mere 0.4 Watts! Even given room for generous inefficiency, something doesn't seem to be adding up. I know that 3xAA chargers can output 500mA @ 5V, so in the real world, I would expect to get at least 1.5~2 Watts output with 2xAA's.

I've also tried some rechargeable NiMH batteries that I have, and had even worse results; only 0.2 Watts.

Why am I only getting a tenth of my expected output?
How can I go about debugging this?

Comment: "*How can I go about debugging this?*" By posting a circuit?

Comment: How are you measuring the current? It sounds like the Pi is not plugged in or not turned on. The voltage is determined by the power source and the current is determined  by the load (provided that the power source is capable of supplying it) - the current quoted for a power source is the maximum current it's designed for.

Comment: Are you aware of maximum power operating points where impedances are matched to source referred to input. With conservation of energy, the impedance ratio is the square of the voltage ratio neglecting losses.

Comment: @immibis I'm charging a mobile battery to draw current. I also tried a USB lightbulb, which normally draws 0.6A @ 5V. I got 0.3ish Amps with the voltage sagging down to 3.5V(!!). That's about 1W. Also tried my radio which can draw up to 250mA, but only got 40-80 depending on the battery I used.

Comment: Check all your resistance losses and ref. des. parameters for differences

Comment: You must have done something wrong, let me guess.. or just buy one that works https://a.pololu-files.com/picture/0J4685.400.jpg?1312c91af848d4a472b166b73bb8be1a

Comment: AA Panasonic batteries, each with a voltage of 1.5 V? Did you look closely to the input/output specs of the boost converter?

Comment: @LukeDupont READ THE FIRST COMMENT AND ACT ON IT.

Comment: @andy-aka Ah, I should have been clearer; I am using a manufactured boost converter; I did not make the circuit.

Comment: Trying to debug commercial parts that don't have a schematic usually means the question is closed down because it's just guesswork. [Read this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boost converters are rated by input current, so a 600mA boost converter can't make 600mA at 5V with a 3V input

With alkaline cells you should design for 1V per cell unless you want to waste money replacing the AAs when they still have 80% charge,
For 600mA at 5V from 2xAA input you should use boost converter rated at more than  1.5A. eg:  XL6009.

Comment: Oh! It seems I misunderstood what those ratings mean. So, the rated current is absolute and applies at any voltage, and points to the input current, not the output. I completely misunderstood this! Also, thanks for the tip on designing for 1V/cell. I'll go ahead and mark this as the accepted answer.